# Select data within specific month in SELECT-OPTIONS

Tags: select, parameters, report, abap, monthcalendar

This ABAP code works but it works only once. I run this code with different parameters but result data does not change. How can I solve it?

```
PARAMETERS : S_MONTH LIKE ISELLIST-MONTH OBLIGATORY.
SELECT-OPTIONS : S_DATE FOR SY-DATUM.
AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR S_MONTH.
PERFORM GET_DATES.

FORM GET_DATES.
 DATA: MONTH     LIKE ISELLIST-MONTH,
       FIRST_DAY LIKE SY-DATUM,
       LAST_DAY  LIKE SY-DATUM.
 MONTH = SY-DATUM+0(6).  "default
 CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_SELECT_MONTH'
  EXPORTING
   ACTUAL_MONTH   = MONTH
  IMPORTING
   SELECTED_MONTH = MONTH.
 IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
 "put some message
 ENDIF.
 CONCATENATE MONTH '01' INTO FIRST_DAY.

 CALL FUNCTION 'RP_LAST_DAY_OF_MONTHS'
  EXPORTING
   DAY_IN            = FIRST_DAY
  IMPORTING
   LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH = LAST_DAY.
 IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.
  "put some message
 ENDIF.

 S_DATE-LOW = FIRST_DAY.
 S_DATE-HIGH = LAST_DAY.
 S_DATE-SIGN = 'I'.
 S_DATE-OPTION = 'BT'.
 APPEND S_DATE.

 S_MONTH = MONTH.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @vwegert  I run this code firstly it is perfect but .I can change parameter select optıon dont changed .select optıon data is prevıous data.How I solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
REFRESH S_DATE.
```

before the

```
APPEND S_DATE.
```

You are now just appending every selection you make.